# How to trigger Kafka rebalance?

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to test my golang service against kafka rebalancing. How can I trigger it manually?

I run kafka locally in Docker. I have one broker. Is there any way force kafka to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kafka doesn't rebalance; consumer groups do.

You'd need to run multiple instances of your consumer, then stop a few instances and observe the behavior of the running instance(s)