# How to check that Kafka does rebalance?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm writing a Go service that works with Kafka. I have a problems with bad commits when broker rebalances. I want to do an experiment forcing Kafka to rebalance and to see how the service behaves.

What I do:

- running Kafka in Docker locally (broker, zookeeper, schema registry and control center)
- created a topic with 2 partition
- running producer that sends messages to both partitions

Then I'm running two consumers with the same `groupID`, after that I'm closing one. It seems to me that broker should start rebalancing this moment. Or no? Who's logs should I check for it?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly?  What is a "bad commit"? Again, [Brokers don't "rebalance". Consumer groups do...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70094702/how-to-trigger-kafka-rebalance)

Answer (score 1):

You can check that by running the following commands:

```sh
bin/kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server host:9092 --list
```

and to describe:

```sh
bin/kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server host:9092 --describe --group foo
```

Full documentation could be found here: [Kafka consumer group](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#:%7E:text=A%20consumer%20group%20is%20a,the%20consumers%20in%20the%20group.)

Comment: What I need is to see some logs like "rebalance started". These commands above allows to see consumer group details

Comment: @Yura Running this command periodically will show active/inactive clients leave/join the group. Other than this, the Go client library will have to be implemented to log the partition assignment actions of the consumer (in Java, this is implemented, not sure of other libraries)

Answer (score 0):

> Who's logs should I check for it?

The running consumer's log should be checked, depending on if the library you're using actually logs such information.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the part of you question about what logs to check: Our log4 configuration causes kafka to produce a 'server.log' and a 'kafkaServer.out' file (not sure if these are standard names or just what we chose to name them). In both of those I see log statements that say, basically, 'Preparing to rebalance group [ourgroupid] with old generation....'